# InnerHTML creates new nodes (new references) each time

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a document object via `DOMImplementation.createHTMLDocument()` and i'm inserting some html with the innerHTML property.
after that i'm appending the nodes to the realdom like this:

```
function appenderController (nodes,target,uid){

    for(let i = 0 ; i < nodes.children.length ; i++) {
        if(nodes.children[i].children.length > 0){
            if(nodes.nodeType === "9"){
                appenderController(nodes.children[i],target);
                continue;
            }

            let realnode = appender(target, nodes.children[i]);
            appenderController(nodes.children[i],realnode);

        }
        if (uid && nodes.children[i].nodeName.toLowerCase() === uid) {
            nodes.children[i].remove();
            return;
        }
        appender(target, nodes.children[i]);
    }




}
```

in some cases i'm adding more html to our document and because innerhtml creates the entire document again so i'm also adding special attribute to each node to keep track on which nodes i've already appended. 
the problem arises when i'm calling `appenderController` recursively with `nodes = fakedocument.body` but inside another function  i'm updating the innerhtml for our fakedocument and on the next iteration of appenderController it will continue iterating on the old fakedocument.body , how can i keep the reference to my fake document even if i use innerhtml and update the nodes again

EXAMPLE:

```
var html='
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="somediv1"></div>
    </body>
    </html>'
;

var dom = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument();

dom.documentElement.innerHTML = html;

var body = dom.body;

var html2='
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="somediv1"></div>
    <div id="somediv2"></div>
    </body>
    </html>'
;

dom.documentElement.innerHTML = html2;
```

now if we look at "body" var we will not have "somediv2" , that's exactly what's happening in my function , in some point i'm updating the innerhtml of my fake document but the "appenderController" continues to iterate with the old nodes

Comment: innerHTML property is of type string, so data is serialized as a string. Serialized means there is no reference to whatever was serialized at first place. Just don't use innerHTML, use appendChild method of the DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

Assign each element a unique ID.  Then access elements by ID, both on the real DOM, and the temporary one.

Do not store references to elements, store their IDs instead.

—

You can also `import` nodes from one `DOM` into another instead of replacing the entire tree using innerHTML.  That approach will not interfer with iterating parent elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode

Comment: i'm assigning each element a unique id , but the problem occurs when i'm updating my document object with some new innerhtml  , and when the "appenderController" continue to iterate it actually holds the old document.body so if i will try document.body.parentNode i will get null because it's no longer part of my document after i updated my document object

Comment: I've managed to fix this by setting a special flag that i check on each iteration of "appenderController" and when i add new html via innerhtml than i set this flag to true and when the execution will return to "appenderController" and the flag is true than appenderController will return itself again with the new document, i think there is a better and much more elegant solution for this if you can come up with something better that will be great

Comment: I suggest that instead of using document.body.parentNode, you call document.getElementById('myParentNode').  When you create your temp DOM, give IDs to all the nodes you want access to.

Comment: Buy the second part of my answer was to import the nodes.  You remove all children from document.body.parentNode, and then import them from your other document.  I will add link to answer.

Comment: I think you still don't understand the problem exactly, if i will do something like that var body = fakedocument.body; fakedocument.documentElement.innerhtml = newhtml ; , now the body holds multiple nodes but not the updated nodes after i updated the innerhtml , do you understand now?>

Comment: Yes I understand the problem.  If you call innerhtml, there is *no way* you can hold references to the old nodes.  You will need to access them by ID or selector.

Comment: yes i know that but if i add html via the innerhtml it won't help me to use selectors because the nodes doesn't exist in the old body

Comment: From what I gather, you are calling sethtml on both your real and fake document.  Your example is a bit vague.  I am sure there is a more elegant solution.  I suggest updating your question with a bit more context on the documents in question and a working example.